# how to generate a sql query from GET

Tags: php, get

I have an associated array retrieved from get, and I wanted to generate the "where clause" of a sql query string using the data in the array.

```
$get_array = ['title'=>'abc', 'author'=>'John']
```

I have created a template array with different strings for different field names, and then loop it through the get array to generate a clause array:

```
$tpl = ['title'  =>  'title LIKE ?',
        'author' =>  'author LIKE ?',
       ];

$where_clause_array = [];
$binding_array = [];

foreach ($get_array as $field_name => $field_value){
  foreach ($tpl as $table_field_title => $tpl_string) {
    if ( $field_name == $table_field_title ) {
      $where_clause_array[] = $tpl_string;
      $binding_array[] = $field_value;
    }
  }
}

$clause_string = implode(' AND ', $where_clause_array);
```

As a result I will get a string like "title LIKE ? AND author LIKE ?". But the problem I have is that I have a clause string that takes two values instead of one:

```
'year_start=>2000', 'year_end=>2017'
'year BETWEEN ? AND ?'
```

I couldn't figure out how to put this into the loop.

Comment: what do you mean by "But the problem I have is that I have a clause string that takes two values instead of one:"

Comment: my loop only takes one element from the get_array and attached one string at a time, but one of the string needs to take 2 elements, which doesn't go with the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before we get to my solution, I want to point out that you don't need to the nested `foreach` statements.  You only need to loop through all the keys in the template once each, so the following code will get the same result as what you currently have:

```
foreach ($tpl as $table_field_title => $tpl_string) {
    if (array_key_exists($table_field_title, $get_array)) {
        $where_clause_array[] = $tpl_string;
        $binding_array[] = $get_array[$table_field_title];
    }
}
```

Building on this, we just need to allow you to do the insert into the `$binding_array` multiple times in each iteration if you have multiple values for any given parameter.

So this will do the job:

```
foreach ($tpl as $table_field_title => $tpl_string) {
    if (array_key_exists($table_field_title, $get_array)) {
        $where_clause_array[] = $tpl_string;

        $field_value = $get_array[$table_field_title];

        if (gettype($field_value) != 'array') $field_value = Array($field_value);

        foreach ($field_value as $value) {
            $binding_array[] = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

You just need to adjust your template:

```
$tpl = array('title' => 'title LIKE ?', 'author' => 'author LIKE ?', 'dates' => 'year BETWEEN ? AND ?');
```

and your input data:

```
$get_array = array('title' => 'abc', 'author' => 'John', 'dates' => array('2000', '2017'));
```

The end result would be like this:

```
$clause_string = implode(' AND ', $where_clause_array);
echo $clause_string . '<br>';
var_dump($binding_array);

// title LIKE ? AND author LIKE ? AND year BETWEEN ? AND ?
// array(4) { [0]=> string(3) "abc" [1]=> string(4) "John" [2]=> string(4) "2000" [3]=> string(4) "2017" }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use BETWEEN, due to the way you're trying to abstract your query building while still using non-normalized field names for the GET parameters, it's simpler to use a year >= ? clause and another year <= ? clause separately.

Also, if you're going to abstract your query building you don't have to define a template for every field, just choose a default operator (e.g. the LIKE one) and consider everything else as an override.

Here's a code sample I prepared for you that will allow you to keep using the GET params you've while allowing you to only worry about defining the overrides (i.e. non-standard behavior):

```
<?php
$get_array = [
    'title' => 'abc',
    'author' => 'John',
    'year_start' => '2000'
    'year_end' => '2017'
];

$overrides = [
    'year_start' => ['column' => 'year', 'operator' => '>='],
    'year_end' => ['column' => 'year', 'operator' => '<=']
];

$where_clause_array = [];
$binding_array = [];

foreach ($get_array as $field_name => $field_value){
    if(isset($overrides[$field_name])){
        $override = (object) $overrides[$field_name]; // Use an object as its syntax for accessing properties is shorter than array (e.g. $object->property vs $object['property'])
        $column = $override->column ?: $field_name; // If override has a column name use it, otherwise ues the field name in the GET params
        $where_clause_array[] = "{$column} {$override->operator} ?";
    }
    else{
        $where_clause_array[] = "{$field_name} LIKE ?"; // We use LIKE as default operator, but we could use = instead and just LIKE in the overrides instead
    }

    $binding_array[] = $field_value;
}

$clause_string = implode(' AND ', $where_clause_array);
```

Hope it helps. If it does, please mark the question answered, and let me know if you've any additional questions, I'm happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_walk function.

Please Try the below code to get a query in all conditions (ie: if year_start or year_end is null):

```
$test_array = ['title'=>'abc', 'author'=>'John', 'year_start'=>2000, 'year_end'=>2017];
$tpl = array();
array_walk($test_array, function(&$a, $b) use (&$tpl,&$test_array) {
if($b == 'year_start' || $b == 'year_end'){
   if($b == 'year_start' && $a){
       if($test_array['year_end'] != NULL){
           $tpl['dates'] = 'year BETWEEN ? AND ?';
       }else{
           $tpl['dates'] = 'year > ?';
       }
   }
    if($b == 'year_end' && $a && !isset($tpl['dates'])){
        $tpl['dates'] = 'year < ?';
    }
}else{
    $tpl[$b] = "$b LIKE ?";
}
});

print_r($tpl);
```